# Method implementation

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am quite new to java and need help in setting up the implementation of the method in a more sophisticated way - I have written this, but was told I need to use one of the GoF patterns in order to beautify it. Some help as to what I need to do would be most appropriated

```
protected void setWeapon() {
        if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("FighterJet")) {
            this.weapon = new GuidedMissileSystem();
            System.out.println("FighterJet " + id + " equipped with " + weapon.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } else if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("AttackHelicopter")) {
            this.weapon = new GrenadeLauncher();
            System.out.println("AttackHelicopter " + id + " equipped with " + weapon.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } else if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Tank")) {
            this.weapon = new Cannon();
            System.out.println("Tank " + id + " equipped with " + weapon.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } else if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("InfantryMobilityVehicle")) {
            this.weapon = new MachineGun();
            System.out.println("InfantryMobilityVehicle " + id + " equipped with " + weapon.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } else if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Warship")) {
            this.weapon = new RocketLauncher();
            System.out.println("Warship " + id + " equipped with " + weapon.getClass().getSimpleName());
        } else if (this.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("Submarine")) {
            this.weapon = new TorpedoTube();
            System.out.println("Submarine " + id + " equipped with " + weapon.getClass().getSimpleName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Note that using the simple name of a class to determine class-specific behaviour isn't necessarily the best idea: if you create another class with the same simple name in another package (e.g. `foo. FighterJet` and `bar. FighterJet`), you'd be forced to give the two classes the same behaviour.

Comment: Design Patterns are not embellishments to sprinkle over your code. If you do not know what design pattern to use you can not use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AndyTurner's answer can be illustrated by the following diagram:

[image: Solution Diagram]

Although this solution works, I disagree that it follows the Dependency Inversion principle, since the concrete classes are responsible for creating the `Weapon` objects. Furthermore, I belive it violates the Open-Closed Principle. Imagine that your `Weapon` is crashed during a battle. You couldn't just replace it for another.

I like to propose another solution, that is structurally similar, but functionally different:

[image: Solution 2 Diagram]

```
interface WarVehicle {
    boolean atack(WarVehicle other);
    boolean defend(WarVehicle from);
    void setWeapon(WarVehicle from);
    Weapon getWeapon();
    boolean acceptsWeapon();
}

abstract class AbstractWarVehicle {
    private Weapon weapon;
    public AbstractWarVehicle(Weapon weapon) {
        setWeapon(weapon);
    }

    public final void setWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        if (!acceptsWeapon(weapon)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Weapon of type " 
                + weapon.getClass().getName() 
                + " cannot be added to WarVehicle of type " 
                + this.getClass().getName());
        }
        this.weapon = weapon;
    }

    public final Weapon getWeapon() {
        return this.weapon;
    }

    public boolean attack(WarVehicle other) {
        if (other != this) {
           return !other.defend(this);
        }
    }

    public boolean defend(WarVehicle from) {
        return this.getWeapon().getDefensePower() >= 
               from.getWeapon().getFirePower();
    }
}

class FighterJet extends AbstractWarVehicle {
    public boolean acceptsWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        return weapon instanceof GuidedMissilesystem;
    }
}

class AttackHelicopter extends AbstractWarVehicle {
    public boolean acceptsWeapon(Weapon weapon) {
        return weapon instanceof GrenadeLauncher;
    }
}

// And so on...
```

Using it:

```
Weapon jet = new FighterJet(new GuidedMissleSystem()); // OK
Weapon jet2 = new FighterJet(new Cannon()); // throws!
```

### Advantages of this approach:

- It's a DIP implementation.
- It's possible to just replace a `Weapon` with a similar one by using `setWeapon`.
- It respects (to a certain extent) the OCP, as it's possible to subclass/compose `Weapon`s. A `FighterJet` will accept anything that is an instance of `GuidedMissileSystem`, which means if your game is expanded and you get a `SuperUltraMegaBlasterGeorgeForemanMissileSystem`, you will still be able to use it if it inherits from `GuidedMissileSystem`.

### Drawbacks of this approach:

- The rules in `acceptsWeapon` are static, so they can't be changed on runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Since this appears to be based on which subclass the instance is concretely, you could simply set a field in the constructor.

For instance:

```
class ParentClass {
  final Weapon weapon;

  ParentClass(Weapon weapon) {
    this.weapon = weapon;
  }
}
```

Then, in the `Warship` class:

```
class Warship extends ParentClass {
  Warship() {
    super(new RocketLauncher());
  }
}
```

(Visibility modifiers and other fields omitted for clarity)

Mind you, [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) isn't a GoF pattern, I don't think. It's just the cleanest one to use here.